# routed component not displaying in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple react page with a navbar and a single route.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component"
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <br />
        <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

create-user.component.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class CreateUser extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>You are on the Create User component!</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The navbar displays ok but if I add in the route the navbar disappears and the routed page doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Route path="/user" element={<CreateUser />} />
```

Comment: ok, then try this:

      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <br />
        <Router>
        <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
        </Router>
      </div>

Comment: not I'm afraid not :(

Comment: You haven't wrapped your <Route></Route> in <Routes></Routes>
It should be <Router><Routes><Route></Route></Routes></Router>
let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `react-router-v6` then component don't support anymore this is the correct syntax

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar />
        <br />
       <Routes>
        <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUser />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/user" />} />
       </Routes>
      </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

i also recommend go through documentation first because there is quite changes in `react router`

[React Router Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)

Comment: thanks but returns this error ```ERROR in src/App.js
  Line 16:35:  'Navigate' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef```

Comment: import this `Navigate` from react router to used it just like you do `route`

Comment: and what version you are using right now for `react router dom` ?

Answer (score 0):

downgrading react router dom "resolved" the issue, not ideal but at least it works now :)

`npm uninstall react-router-dom && npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0`

Comment: The other option is to [update your code to the `react-router-dom@6` APIs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5). I don't know why you think reverting to a compatible version (*for your current code*) isn't ideal or why you say it only "resolved" the issue.